# Java Proxy Output Stream corrupted with null bytes

Tags: java, jsp, proxy

We have a JSP which is supposed to fetch a PDF from an internal URL and pass this PDF on to the client (like a proxy).

The resulting download is corrupted. After about 18'400 bytes we only get 00 bytes till the end. Interestingly the download is exactly the right size in bytes.

[image: binary difference]

```
    // Get the download
    URL url = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection req = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    req.setDoOutput(true);
    req.setRequestMethod("GET");

    // Get Binary Response
    int contentLength = req.getContentLength();
    byte ba[] = new byte[contentLength];
    req.getInputStream().read(ba);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);

    // Prepare Reponse Headers
    response.setContentType(req.getContentType());
    response.setContentLength(req.getContentLength());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.pdf");

    // Stream to Response
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    //OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\op.pdf");
    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) output.write(buffer, 0, count);

    in.close();
    output.close();

    req.disconnect();
```

UPDATE 1: I'm not the only one seeing Java stop streaming at 4379 bytes ([link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1206095?start=0&tstart=0)).

UPDATE 2: If I do output.flush after every write I get more data 14599 bytes and then the nulls. Must have something to do with tomcat's output buffer limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int contentLength = req.getContentLength();
byte ba[] = new byte[contentLength];
req.getInputStream().read(ba);
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);

// Prepare Reponse Headers
response.setContentType(req.getContentType());
response.setContentLength(req.getContentLength());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.pdf");

// Stream to Response
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
//OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\op.pdf");
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) output.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

This code is all nonsense. You are ignoring the result of the first `read()` and you are also wasting both time and space with the `ByteArrayInputStream`. All you need is this:

```
int contentLength = req.getContentLength();

// Prepare Reponse Headers
response.setContentType(req.getContentType());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.pdf");

// Stream to Response
InputStream in = req.getInputStream();
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) output.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

Note that the Content-Length is already set for you.

Comment: Looks like we just overlapped! You are correct the code I posted is uninformed copy-paste nonsense.